# Adding Bootstrap files to IntelliJ project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, intellij-idea

I'm importing the Bootstrap distribution files to an IntelliJ project. The Bootstrap files exist on my filesystem, outside of the IntelliJ project. There is no way (as far as I could tell) of having IntelliJ perform the import. I copied the files manually to the appropriate directory in the IntelliJ project. I have 2 questions.

First, for files bootstrap-theme.css.map and bootstrap-them.css.min, IntelliJ prompted me to select a filetype. I selected "text". Is this the correct type?

Second, after importing the Bootstrap CSS files, the Project window appeared as shown in the attached image. In the bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css directory, files bootstrap.css.map, boostrap.theme.min.css, bootstrap.css.map and bootstrap.min.css appear as subdirectories to files bootstrap.css and bootstrap-theme.css. I think this is just a result of how IntelliJ interprets "." when working with files/directories. So the question is, should I just ignore this, and is there a way to make the files in this directory (just this directory) look like a normal list of files, i.e., all at the same level.

[image]

Comment: You can go look in finder how the filestructure is. I think you should be Ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Nope, you don't associate `.map` and `.css.min` to a text file format. To import the bootstrap files to `IntelliJ`, you can just drag and drop all the files in one go to the desired folder. Another way is to open the IntelliJ project folder in the filesystem and paste the files directly there. You can use `Show in explorer` option when you right click on the folder to open the filesystem folder location.

2) This is absolutely fine. IntelliJ is just grouping the files based on common starting characters.